# AndEngine - setText on Text entity causing hiccups in first seconds

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

Imagine score counter made with Text() entity. Simple.

After I start a game, calling `setText()` causes launching a `GC_EXPLICIT` that slows down a game causing freezes, and after a few calls - problem disappears. Firstly I thought it's a problem with Strings and concatenation in Java, so I used a StringBuilder. The problem still exists. If I change `setText("$" + score + "M")` to simple `setText("0")` no hiccups are noticed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in `Font`. Creation of `Texture` doesn't actually load characters to this `Texture`! All you need to do is after creating `Font` simply call:

`pFont.prepareLetters("0123456789".toCharArray());`
with all chars you need.

Answer (score 0):

Occasional hiccups that were caused by `GC_EXPLICIT` were happening because Font in `update()` was explicitly calling `System.gc()`. Removing this line we were back on track below the green line, yeah! 60fps.

However, the author of AndEngine might had reasons for this explicit call. Since the stages are short we granted our app call this `gc()` when the `GameScene` is paused, quit or stage complete, anywhere where there is no excessive animation.

Preparing characters upfront did not sooth the hiccups, because the texts were dynamic and we could not prepare all possible characters to keep the `System.gc()` in this method, but honor it later.

Indeed preparing the letters upfront does not trigger `GC_EXPLICIT`, as it is described in the answer provided by the OP.

**EDIT**:

After some research, another thing that caused < 60fps, was the `SoundPool`, we should have playing a sound with volume `0f,0f` and looping, in order to prevent the `SoundPool` reset to idle state and rearm again.